# Setting up Google Protocol Buffer(C++) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, protocol-buffers

I am a newbie to C++. I tried setting up Google Protocol Buffers to Visual Studio 2015 and find it real hard to execute a very simple program. It would be great, If someone could guide me on how to set up google protocol buffers on Visual Studio 2015.

I followed the steps in http://forums.4fips.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=807. But still it is not successful.

Comment: Please ask for specific problems here. This is not a tutoring site.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962972/protobuf-c-extensions-use